# Get matching values from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 6 tables with IDs of customers. 
It is posible, in one query, to get the customers ids that coincide in all tables?
In my example, the customers ids that results are 8 and 9
(it must be taken into account, that in practice, any of the tables may have values ​​or not)

Many thanks
Best regards

```
DECLARE @TCustomerAge  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


DECLARE @TCustomerLocalization  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


DECLARE @TCustomerGroup  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


DECLARE @TCustomerStore  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


DECLARE @TCustomerSales  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


DECLARE @TCustomerPayment  TABLE(
CustomerID  INT not null ); 


--@TCustomerAge empty
insert into @TCustomerLocalization values (8), (9), (11)
insert into @TCustomerGroup values (8), (9), (10), (11)
insert into @TCustomerStore values (8), (9), (11)
--@@TCustomerSales empty
insert into @TCustomerPayment values (2), (3), (5), (8), (9), (10)

-- Result -> 8, 9
```

Comment: If the ID had to be in all tables would the result of this query be nothing as you have 2 empty tables?  And why would 8,9,11 be the right answer as only 8 and 9 show up in all tables that have data?

Comment: in those tables, I save the ids that meet certain rules, for that reason it is possible that exists empty tables. Sorry for the result mistake, I correct it

Comment: Seems to me this would be a full outer join between all the tables on customerID where customerID is not null in any of the tables.

Comment: And what do you want returned if a table has no rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with CteAllIDs as (
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerAge UNION
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerLocalization UNION
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerGroup UNION
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerStore UNION
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerSales UNION
    SELECT CustomerID FROM @TCustomerPayment
)
SELECT CteAllIDs.CustomerID
FROM CteAllIDs
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerAge WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerAge))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerLocalization WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerLocalization))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerGroup WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerGroup))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerStore WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerStore))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerSales WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerSales))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerPayment WHERE CustomerID = CteAllIDs.CustomerID) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TCustomerPayment))
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle empty tables, perhaps `union` would be a better approach:

```
with t as (
      select id, '@TCustomerAge' as tablename from @TCustomerAge 
      union  -- uses union to remove duplicates within tables
      select id, '@TCustomerLocalization' from @TCustomerLocalization
      union
      . . .
     )
select t.id
from t cross join
     (select count(distinct tablename) as n from t) n
group by t.id, n.n
having count(*) = n.n;
```

Empty tables are not represented in `t`, so the `count(distinct)` only counts tables that are present.